# Gherkin i18n plugin for Atom text editor

Tags: cucumber, atom-editor, gherkin, lettuce, python-behave

I want to use the Atom Text Editor to manage my feature files defined in Gherkin, I saw that there exist on the one hand the [language-gherkin-plugin](https://github.com/gigapixel/atom-language-gherkin) which works very well with syntax coloring in different colors. I'm more interested to use the second [language-gherkin-i18n-plugin](https://github.com/mackoj/language-gherkin-i18n) to define feature files in different languages. The problem is that the syntax coloring doesnt work as expected and shown in the preview on GitHub. Has anyone used the plugin in Atom and was able to run it as expected? Or can someone try it out and give feedback if it works?

My setup is Windows 10 64 Bit and Atom 1.2.3, the plugin will be installed through the package manager!

EDIT: I fixed the package together with the developer, the problem lied in the autodetection of the language with CRLF line ending files. Should work now.

BR